# React Native - How to compare two Animated.Values in shouldComponentUpdate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, react-native, react-native-reanimated

I am optimizing my flatlist items (progressive images) and to avoid extending React.PureComponent I have decided to implement my own shouldComponentUpdate life-cycle method.

My [progressive images](https://medium.com/react-native-training/progressive-image-loading-in-react-native-e7a01827feb7) have two animated values:

> ```
> 1. thumbnailOpacity
> 2. imageOpacity
> ```

And my should component update must look something like this:

```
state = {
   isLoading: true,
   thumbnailOpacity: new Animated.Value(0),
   imageOpacity: new Animated.Value(0)
}

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  /*
    React's PureComponent implement a shouldComponentUpdate with shallow comparison.
    This is expensive here, because it need to check all our props. For a good bit-level performance,
    use the strictest rules for our list item.

    This component must re-render only when the state change.
  */

  return (
     nextState.isLoading !== this.state.isLoading ||
     nextState.thumbnailOpacity !== this.state.thumbnailOpacity ||
     nextState.imageOpacity !== this.state.imageOpacity
  );        
}
```

But as Animated values are not primitive data types, I don't know how to do that without a shallow comparison.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From your state initialisation:

```
state = {
   ...
   thumbnailOpacity: new Animated.Value(0),
   imageOpacity: new Animated.Value(0)
}
```

You should be able to access it like this:

```
this.state.thumbnailOpacity._value
```